# bootloader location

Tags: software-installation

Sorry, an error occured and it was not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location.

How would you like to proceed?

Choose a different device to install the bootloader on:
/dev/sdb

Continue without bootloader.

Cancel installation.

Answer (score 3):

Select the option "Continue without bootloader".After the successfull installation of Ubuntu, don't forget to run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Boot repair will reinstall the grub on your disk.

Comment: Still applies in 2019, over 5 years later.

Comment: It doensn't work for me... :-(

Comment: I think the point here is to run `boot-repair` after installation, but BEFORE restarting. So best select 'continue testing' and then run the boot repair.

Comment: When installing ubuntu 22.04 I didn't see a way to run ubuntu after installing without restarting. The only option was to remove the usb stick and restart

Answer (score 1):

Run live Cd -----> open Terminal :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt ( so you could read and write)
```

`/dev/sdax` is the partition where Ubuntu os is installed.

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

`/dev/sda` represents the first disk.

When installation finish :

```
sudo umount /mnt


Reboot
```