# Sorry, an error occured and it was not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, mount, bootloader

Install fails with:

[image: boot loader]

system:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1001820k,nr_inodes=250455,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=203660k,mode=755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=5d2eac7dbb955a36)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=14150)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=203660k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1553670144 bytes, 3034512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xde273f4f

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 156301311 156299264 74.5G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 72.5 GiB, 77863059456 bytes, 152076288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 2 GiB, 2134900736 bytes, 4169728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 2 GiB, 2134376448 bytes, 4168704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I've tried the `different devices` option to install the bootloader on, but even after clicking "ok" cannot proceed.

How/where to install the bootloader?

I've tried also the `continue without a bootloader` [option](https://askubuntu.com/q/430831/45156) but cannot get past this dialog even after clicking "ok".

Comment: Did you try to choose `/dev/sda`?

Comment: yes, I tried every option listed.  then clicked ok.  cannot get past this dialog.

Comment: Why did you choose `LVM`? That is the problem. Install again without checking the LVM and encryption. You probably checked both option just for fun.

Comment: And why are you installing 17.04, not 16.04 LTS?

Comment: I'm also unable to continue after selection "continue without a bootloader". I can click 'OK', but nothing happens.

Comment: I'm also unable to continue after selection "continue without a bootloader". I can click 'OK', but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unselecting LVM sorta kinda did the trick:

[image: grub]

rebooting now after selecting `sda`.  ultimately worked as:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3b9b7b5e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 156301311 156299264 74.5G 83 Linux
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5882620a-f19a-4553-8c8d-73d59499d2a1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#/swapfile none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
thufir@doge:~$
```

why didn't LVM work?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to start Ubuntu 18.04.3 in my PC; first, some features of it: it is a Lenovo ThinkCentre M810z, that has a 256 GB SSD drive with Windows 10 Pro already installed on it; it also has a 500 GB HDD. At the shop, they recommended that I should install Ubuntu on the HDD, and not on the SDD along Windows 10 Pro, for some unspecified reason. 
Second, I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.3 using the bootable pen drive (as indicated in https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1). Then, I restarted the PC with the pen drive in it and the Ubuntu installer triggered its process as expected; before it finished, though, that error message: "not possible to install the bootloader...". 
To solve it, I downloaded to a bootable pen drive Ubuntu 18.04.1 (from other computer I use at the office), and then started the computer with that pen drive; again, the installer was launched as usual; however, when asked, I ticked the option for installing ubuntu 18.04.1 *alongside* ubuntu 18.04.3 (in a previous attempt, I ticked the option for removing 18.04.3 altogether and installing 18.04.1 alone, but it failed with the same error message of the question). This time around, the installation went smoothly and without error message; just the "Installation finished. Restart your computer" one. I removed the pen drive and restarted the computer, but pushing F1 repeatedly to have access to the boot options. There, I went to Startup>Boot priority order, and used the (+,-) keys as indicated to push 500 GB HDD option to the first place in the priority list, saved the changes and restarted the PC.
The good news: the grub menu finally emerged and Ubuntu 18.04.3 started as expected; the bad news: the grub does not show the option to start Windows 10...I know I would have to rearrange the boot priority order for this to happen (256 GB SDD drive pushed to first place in boot priority order). This situation does not bother me, nonetheless, for I will use Ubuntu for what I plan doing with my PC. Hope this helps. Thank you.