# netbeans won't display projects window

Tags: software-installation, java, netbeans, ide, ubuntu-make

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"

$ java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 9
$ umake --version
16.11.1

$ umake ide netbeans
[sudo] password for thufir: 
Choose installation path: /home/thufir/.local/share/umake/ide/netbeans
Downloading and installing requirements                                                    |
100% |#####################################################################################|
Installing Netbeans
|##########################################################################################|
Installation done

$ netbeans
The program 'netbeans' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install netbeans
```

[image: notifications]

possibly related to:

```
$ /home/thufir/.local/share/umake/bin/netbeans 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/home/thufir/.local/share/umake/ide/netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
^C
```

which is an error I was seeing before a [clean](https://askubuntu.com/q/947116/45156) install.

*(Possibly related to [this error](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/1102), or at least similar.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans 8.2 only works with Oracle JDK 8, but not with JDK 9. I had the exact same problems. (I think Netbeans 9 will work with JDK9, but it's not out yet.)

Comment: I'm going to do a clean install then use sdkman for jvm, jdk and gradle; umake for netbeans.  assuming all that works (I think jdk9 is official now?) will accept the answer.  Sorry for the delay, good answer.