# how to run the process status, ps, utility

Tags: command-line, ps

How do I run the `ps` [utility](https://www.pslinux.online/ps-manual.html)?

```
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ ps -aux
The program 'psql' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install postgresql-client-common
You will have to enable the component called 'main'
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ 
thufir@arrakis:~$ ps aux
The program 'psql' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install postgresql-client-common
You will have to enable the component called 'main'
thufir@arrakis:~$
```

Sometimes it's more applicable than `top`; not sure why `ps` isn't in the [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) as it's a [clean](https://askubuntu.com/a/947275/45156) install.  Seems odd.

How can I cause `ps` to work as normal?

Comment: Type `which ps` to see who bash is calling when you type ps, please

Comment: @Redbob `which ps` will show the first `ps` executable found by searching `$PATH` even if that executable isn't what `bash` will actually run for `ps`. `which` is an external command that doesn't know about shell builtins, aliases, or functions. So it won't help at all here: for example, if `ps` is an alias that runs instead of `/bin/ps` then `which ps` will *still* show `/bin/ps` rather than indicating the alias. **`type ps` or `command -v ps` should be used instead.** (*`ls`* is usually an alias in Ubuntu so the differences can be seen by running `which ls`, `type ls`, and `command -v ls`.)

Comment: Well explained, @EliahKagan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you have an alias from `ps` to `psql` which cause the error.

Instead of running `ps` try running:

- `/bin/ps`

or

- `\ps`

If the problem is indeed an `alias` - running `unalias ps` will temporary remove the alias, and afterwards running `ps` will act as normal.